# Product bundling on product page examples and best practices

Tags: usability, user-behavior, e-commerce

I'm revisiting the product bundling feature (aka complete the look) on the product pages of our company fashion commerce website. At the moment it's at the bottom of the product page and not really performing, I don't believe the placement is really an issue as heat maps show that users are scrolling down. Does anyone know some good examples and best practices of this feature?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? What about helping us with a few examples and your comments that would show your research efforts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People scroll down doesn't necessarily mean that they actually look at the information. Looking at the information also doesn't mean user understand the meaning of the message and try to match to what they are looking for. According to many studies, users nowadays do scroll down, and focus more on the information which is about the fold level. If your company wants to push the product bundling, it is better to place it above fold or just below the fold area. You can read some of the articles below. Hope it helps.

[Do People Read Your Content? 6 Facts about Reading Online](http://blog.trap.it/blog/bid/382592/Do-People-Read-Your-Content-6-Facts-about-Reading-Online)

[Eye tracking research](http://www.nngroup.com/topic/eyetracking/)